# Choosing the same date in php is giving different values, why?

Tags: php

Choosing the same date in php is giving different values .

When i choose the same date in the calendar, it returns me different values, although the method is exactly same, it returns different values.

Like if i choose the date in the calendar 21st of August twice it will give me 2 different values.

I don't have any explanation to solve this problem.

**PHP code:**

```
        $to_date = strtotime($to_dat);
        (date_default_timezone_get() . "<br />");
        (date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $to_date) . "<br />");
        (date_default_timezone_set("UTC") . "<br />");
        (date("Y-d-mTG:i:sz", $to_date) . "<br />");

        echo ($to_date. "</br>");
}
```

**Output:**
Choosing the same date both in from and to 21 of August is giving different values in return.

[image: Output screenshot]

**When i echo ---**

```
        echo ($from_dat. "</br>");
        echo ($to_dat. "</br>");
```

[image]

**it returns ---**

Can anyone solve this problem !

Comment: Different timezones probably, not sure though.

Comment: @HassanAlthaf i sad i select the date on the same time, to how the timezone can be change for 2 date-picker at the same time and also on the same event ! Doesn't make sense !

Comment: Two different values for two different span of time @ChristoferHansen

Comment: can you output only;  from_dat  and $to_dat

Comment: What's - sz  format? I couldn't find it in the php date format manual.

Comment: `strtotime()` uses the current time if not specified, and just fed a date (from what I remember), try exploding by `/` (or other separator character) and feeding into `mktime()`

Comment: @LuckySpoon Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting timezone to UTC "after" setting `$from_date` value.

You should (assuming that you put `date_default_timezone_get()` and other lines for testing purposes) remove the lines containing `date_default_timezone_set("UTC")` and it'll probably work as intended.

Or, set time zone to UTC from begining, either of these will get you the same time stamp. You'll have to decide which time zone you want.